# What kind of electrical fixture is this?

Tags: electrical

The fixture is near the ceiling in the closet of master bedroom. [image: mystery electrical fixture]

Answer (score 5):

It's a transformer, most likely for your doorbell.

Some security systems use them too.

Comment: Doorbell is in hallway, closer to the front door. I can't imagine how the transformer would be useful for the doorbell. But there was previously a comprehensive security system in the house (all windows and doors), so your comment gives me a hunch it's left over from that.

Comment: Is the transformer powered? What is the voltage across the two screws? There is a wire connected and coiled around it. Does this wire go anywhere into the wall or is it terminated? If you loosen one screw and pull the wire away, does the doorbell still work? My door gong transformer (20 V ac is in a utility closet across a hall from the gong itself.

Comment: The transformer for the doorbell does not need to be located next to the doorbell,  just like a light switch does not need to be located right next to the light fixture.  Power could come in to the transformer from the backside and then wires running from it to the doorbell.

Comment: @Anticipation doorbells usually work on low voltage, to avoid the fundamental problem that rain water (or ice, fog, etc), mechanical push buttons, and mains electricity don't play well together.